# How to Generate a Laravel Image URL when creating a Image Element Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code.But it displays the alt ("na") when I run it in the browser. which I think means that the url is not working correctly. I however cannot understand why.

```
    var tbl_img=document.createElement("img");
    tbl_img.setAttribute('src', "('{{ asset('Images/Table2.png') }}')");
    tbl_img.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    tbl_img.style.width= '64px';
    tbl_img.style.width= '64x';
```

But The below Code worked so I know the URL is working Fine.

```
    div.style.backgroundImage = "url('{{ asset('Images/Table2.png') }}')";
```

The Question being, How do I generate a JavaScript Image URL when using Laravel.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong I changed the above code to. 

`tbl_img.setAttribute('src', "{{ asset('Images/Table2.png') }}");`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's a mistake from me, or really like that in your code, but have you tried to type EXACTLY the same thing ?

```
tbl_img.setAttribute('src', "('{{ asset('Images/Table2.png') }}')");
```

to

```
tbl_img.setAttribute('src', "url('{{ asset('Images/Table2.png') }}')");
```

Comment: I tried adding the url as you did as well but it still didn't work